# Maya Scale Constraint

Tags: python, maya

I have two list

```
mainCTRL = ['nurbsCircle1','nurbsCircle2','nurbsCircle3']
grpCTRL = ['group1','group2','group3']
```

and for each object in mainCTRL and grpCTRL, I am trying to apply scale constraint to its same order in the grpCTRL. Scale should be apply in the order, like

```
'nurbsCicle1' should apply scale constraint to 'group1'
'nurbsCicle2' should apply scale constraint to 'group2'
'nurbsCicle3' should apply scale constraint to 'group3'
```

How can I have do this? How can I tell python to apply this command for each nurbsCircle to its grpCTRL.

```
cmds.scaleConstraint('eachnubrsCircle', 'eachgrp')
```

I am a newbie to python and learning things as I go. Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively easy with Python's `zip` method.

```
mainCTRL = ['nurbsCircle1','nurbsCircle2','nurbsCircle3']
grpCTRL = ['group1','group2','group3']

for ctrl, grp in zip(mainCTRL, grpCTRL):
    cmds.scaleConstraint(ctrl, grp)
```

You can print `zip(mainCTRL, grpCTRL)` to see what it's actually returning.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just what I needed :)